# PARI to Mathematica conversion

Tags: function-construction, conversion, integer-sequence

I need to use the coefficients T(n,k) in my algorithm and I found a program in PARI

Can anybody translate this code to mathematica?

```
{T (n, k) = 
if (n == 0, 1, 
if (k == 0, 1, 
  if (k == n, 3^n*(3^n - sum (j = 0, n - 1, T (n, j)/3^j)), 
    polcoeff ((Ser (vector (n, i, T (n - 1, i - 1)), x) + 
         x*O (x^k))^((n + 1)/n), k, x))))}
```

Comment: If you are planning on using *Mathematica* a lot, then this is a great exercise to do yourself. I really think it's worth sitting down and trying to figure this out on your own.

Comment: i tried, but I have some problems with Ser,vector part...

Comment: Well, I can't help you with that, because I don't know PARI syntax. Perhaps you should edit your post to include what you have so far, and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Probably better off to start from the math; that is, where did you get this code from? Can you describe what you're trying to compute here?

Comment: The math is here A097186 https://oeis.org/A097186 .I need this coefficients plus some other strange stuff...

Comment: Try this: `Table[SeriesCoefficient[3 y/((1 - 9 x y) + (3 y - 1)*(1 - 9 x y)^(2/3)), {x, 0, j}, {y, 0, k}], {j, 0, 8}, {k, 0, j}]`. (I used the generating function given there.)

Comment: OK.. I believe I can make it to T(n,k) from here... Thanks